# Spring Kotlin Webapp without Webflux need to perform 2 tasks concurrently to yield a result best way

Tags: spring, kotlin, concurrency, async-await, spring-webclient

The app does not use webflux and reactive programming, it use a normal `CrudRepository` to connect to a database that some time takes long time to respond, and it use the `WebClient` to perform requests to other services but using `block()` function to get the result in a synchronous way. I want to change the following code so both calls happen concurrently:

```
@Service class CustomerService(
    val profileClient: WebClient,
    val customerRepository: CustomerRepository
) {

    fun getCustomer(id: String) : CustomerData {
        val customer = customerRepository.findById(id)
        val profile  = profileClient.get().uri("/v1/profile/{id}", id)
                           .retrieve().bodyToMono<Profile>()
                           .block()
        return CustomerData(customer, profile)
    }

}
```

If the call to `customerRepository.findById(id)` takes lets say 20 millis, and the `profileClient.get..` takes 50 millis, the overall takes 70 millis, while if I call both calls concurrently, it should take around 50 millis.

I cannot migrate the app to a fully reactive version with Webflux due it has a lot of code to migrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need concurrency, you may use [kotlin's coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html).

Your code would look like this:

```
fun getCustomer(id: String) : CustomerData = runBlocking {
    val customer = async { customerRepository.findById(id) }
    val profile  = async { profileClient.get().uri("/v1/profile/{id}", id)
                       .retrieve().bodyToMono<Profile>()
                       .block() }
    CustomerData(customer.await(), profile.await())
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Neo it worked! what I couldn't check yet is how this scale and perform in high demand workloads, `runBlocking` doesn't see to allow to setup a thread pool, I'm not sure yet reading the doc whether it uses the same thread that called the `async { ... }` blocks, or it uses a global thread pool and what are the limitations, in that case for low loads it reduces the response time drastically, but in highloads it can turn your service down or make it even slower, just trying to figure out...

Comment: @MarianoRuiz With coroutines you don't need to care about thread pools, but only Coroutine-Context. Since coroutines are very light-weight (and I use them very often in high numbers in my production env) I can't tell you a limit since I never reached any. You may try for yourself and read some kotlin doc about context and dispatchers - they can be very powefull - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html